InteractiveViewer scaled view center
I'm trying to get the center of a scaled view in InteractiveViewer. I know how to get the focal point because it is included in the onInteractionUpdate event data, but I'm not sure how to get or calculate the center of the scaled view. Is anyone able to give me any hints what should I do or if there is better way to implement zoom with information about center point of the zoomed area?
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    color: const Color(0xFFFFE306),
    child: InteractiveViewer(
        transformationController: viewTransformationController,
        onInteractionUpdate: (data) {
          // print scaled center here

        },
        boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        minScale: 0.1,
        maxScale: 5,
        //board
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            left: boardOffset.dx,
            top: boardOffset.dy,
            child: GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  setState(() {
                    boardOffset = Offset(boardOffset.dx + details.delta.dx,
                        boardOffset.dy + details.delta.dy);
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                    width: 1000,
                    height: 1000,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 63, 231, 40),
                    child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                      Positioned(
                        left: ((offset.dx - 50) / 50).roundToDouble() * 50,
                        top: (offset.dy / 100).roundToDouble() * 100,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onPanUpdate: (details) {
                            setState(() {
                              offset = Offset(offset.dx + details.delta.dx,
                                  offset.dy + details.delta.dy);
                            });
                          },
                          child: ImageTile(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]))),
          )
        ])));

}

center? In global coordinates (relative to the whole screen), or locally to the InteractiveViewer?

In my case it will be the same because my component will fill the entire screen, so any of them here will be good for me.

check TransformationController.toScene and MatrixUtils.transformPoint methods - they can be used for getting local / global offsets

you can check this gist on how those two methods can be used in practice

thanks for the gist, I made it working by using RenderBox.globalToLocal().
